# ScriptExternalLoadError: Loading script failed

Tags: webpack-5, webpack-module-federation

I am getting this error message :ScriptExternalLoadError: Loading script failed.

(missing: http://localhost:3005/remoteEntry.js).

when trying to load a remote app from the container app in development.

I have this optimization (when I put them in comment everything works) :

```
optimization:{
  runtimeChunk: 'single',
  splitChunks: {
    chunks: 'all',
    cacheGroups: {
      vendor: {
        test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
        name: module => (module.context.match(/[\\/]node_modules[\\/](.*?)([\\/]|$)/) || [])[1]
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: I was facing the same issue!

Answer (score 2):

Because the runtime.js was be split into a separate chunk, but your remoteEntry.js need it. So you can comment the `runtimeChunk: 'single'`, or you can see this solution: [concat-runtime](https://github.com/module-federation/concat-runtime)